# Radio button with link after click

Tags: jquery, wordpress

After clicking on the radio button, a new page will open. I want to add a link to each radio button. And the radio button linked on the active page will also be activated.

Tried the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    var radioValue = $('input:radio:checked').val();
    if (radioValue == 'male') {
      window.location.href = '/connfig';
    }
    if (radioValue == 'ricted') {
      window.location.href = '/stay-ricted';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <label for="male">Male</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">

  <label for="ricted">Ricted</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="ricted" name="ricted" value="ricted">

  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" id="other" name="gender" value="other">
</div>
```

Comment: You are nearly there just use window.open in place of your window.location.href , refer to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp